# Why multivariate normal probability density function is more than 1?

Tags: python, numpy, normal-distribution, probability-density

I am calculating the multivariate normal probability density function and expect to get values between 0 and 1, but if you get the `z.max()` it is around 12, Could you please explain to me why is that? Why it is not between 0 and 1?

```
mean = [0.1907431606674439, 10.776990818051406]
covariance = [[0.003633465420060508, -0.0007978346053959698],
              [-0.0007978346053959698, 0.049307867383681425]]

x, y = np.mgrid[0.05:0.35:.01, 10:11.5:.01]
pos = np.dstack((x, y))
z = multivariate_normal.pdf(pos, mean, covariance)


plt.figure()
plt.contourf(x, y, z)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The (normalised) PDF must *integrate* to 1 when taken over all the possible values of the distribution, but that doesn't mean it can't be above 1 at any point.  For a simple example, consider a uniform distribution on [0, 0.1].  The PDF of that distribution is 10 (for 0 <= x <= 0.1) and 0 elsewhere.  (That's a univariate distribution, to make the example simpler, but the same principle applies to multivariate.)

Comment: so, you mean it is not calculating the probability? if yes, how can I get the probability?

Comment: Let's write `F(x, y)` to mean the PDF evaluated at `(x, y)`.  What that means is that if we consider some very small `δx` and `δy`, then the probability of a result `(X, Y)` such that `x < X < x + δx` and `y < Y < y + δy` is equal to `F(x, y) * δx * δy`.

Comment: Could you please help me with the coding to get the probability? I took a look at the sample code in scipy, it results the probability: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html

Comment: To easily get the probability, usually you need a cdf, not pdf. Otherwise you need to integrate the pdf, which is cumbersome.

Comment: I applied the `EllipticEnvelop' on `iris` dataset and the `multivariate_normal.pdf` and get the probability, but not in this case.

Comment: cdf shows the Cumulative distribution function. If you substitute it with pdf in the code, you see that the results are cumulative values and not probabilities.

Comment: @8Simon8 sure: what exactly are you looking to calculate the probability of? The normal distribution is a continuous distribution, so it's not meaningful to ask "what's the probability of getting the exact value (X, Y)" because there are infinitely many possible values: we always need to ask "what's the probability of (X, Y) lying in a particular range?"

Comment: (btw, the sample graph in the Scipy docs is a PDF too.)

Comment: Here's what is hopefully a good intro to the concepts around continuous probability and PDFs: https://www.probabilisticworld.com/introduction-probability-distributions/#Continuous_probability_distributions

Comment: Thank you all for helping me. What I know from statistics, a multivariate (here in [this graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#/media/File:Multivariate_Gaussian.png) bivariate) density function would be like this graph. For every pair of (x, y), I have a probability and the sum of all probability (under the surface) should be equal to one. So, when I use `multivariate_normal.pdf' which is Probability density function based on the [this link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html), I expect to get sth [0,1]

Comment: `For every pair of (x, y), I have a probability` - this is the root of the question I think.  With continuous distributions, there are infinitely many values, so we **can't** say we have a probability of the **exact** value (x, y).  For example we can't ask "what's the probablity of a sample being exactly (4, 7)?".  We *can* ask "what's the probability of a sample being in the range (3.9 - 4.1, 6.9 - 7.1)?".  Or "...in the range (3.998 - 4.102, 6.999 - 7.101) etc etc".  Those are the kind of things we can write code to calculate, and as you say, those numbers will all be guaranteed to be <= 1.

Comment: (I agree with @j1-lee that CDFs usually provide an easier way to do those calculations.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246680/discussion-between-8simon8-and-slothrop).

Comment: "For every pair of (x, y), I have a probability" That is wrong for continuous random variables/vectors. That holds for discrete random variables/vectors.